# Limit tokens per minute in LangChain, using OpenAI-embeddings and Chroma vector store

Tags: langchain, chromadb, openaiembeddings

I am looking for a way to limit the tokens per minute when saving embeddings in a Chroma vector store. Here is my code:

```
[...]
# split the documents into chunks
text_splitter = CharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1500, chunk_overlap=0)
texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
# select which embeddings we want to use
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
# create the vectorestore to use as the index
db = Chroma.from_documents(texts, embeddings)
[...]
```

I receive the following error:

```
Retrying langchain.embeddings.openai.embed_with_retry.<locals>._embed_with_retry in 4.0 seconds as it raised RateLimitError: Rate limit reached for default-text-embedding-ada-002 in organization org-xxx on tokens per min. Limit: 1000000 / min. Current: 1 / min. Contact us through our help center at help.openai.com if you continue to have issues..
```

As the function `.from_documents` is provided by the langchain/chroma library, it can not be edited. I was wondering if any of you know a way how to limit the tokes per minute when storing many text chunks and embeddings in a vector store? I thought about creating multiple sets of text chunks and safe them set by set to the `db`, for example with the `.persist` function. However, this would overwrite the `db` every time, as far as I understood.
I couldn't find a solution in the langchain or chroma documentation.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Regards

Comment: not yet. I haven't tried harder, though.

Comment: In my case, I just reduced `chunk_size=500` and the code went through.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you can send a limited number of tokens to OpenAI.

The solution I found is to feed it to OpenAI slowly. I expected Chroma to have a rate limiter, but I could not find such thing. Below code did it for me

After you created your database

```
for splitted_document in all_splits:
  vectorstore.from_documents(documents=[splitted_document], embedding=OpenAIEmbeddings(), persist_directory=base_path)
  time.sleep(60)
```